# Configure Nexus N9K-C93180YC-EX

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus

I am configuring a switch for the 1st time (Cisco Nexus N9000 Switch) to do some server performance testing in my lab.

I have the serial console working and can log into the switch and run commands.

I want to do the following

```
1) Give the switch a static IP for remote management
2) Activate all the ports on the switch
3) Create a few VLANs with 8 or more ports each
```

The commands that I have tried so far for 1,2&3 haven't worked. I would really appreciate how I can do 1,2 & 3

Comment: Have you looked at the manual?

Comment: So *which* commands did you try, and what error message did you get?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure this switch is in Nexus OS mode. 
This switch is delivered from CISCO in ACI mode, to configure 1,2 & 3 you need to make it in nexus mode which requires below steps:

1. Install the Nexus OS into switch: You can contact TAC or may refer online
2. Check Show version: it should show the NX OS
3. Now you can configure 1,2,3